# How to read multiple .equals statements in if statements

Tags: java

I am struggling on a problem, I am creating a virtual human interface where one could talk to the computer and it will respond to what you are saying. So I went and took a string and chopped it into words(`split()` function), all easy. Know if I want the PC to respond when certain words are in the string, but it doesn't.  It keeps on terminating the program when I put in a String that contains *"hi"* , *"how"* or *"you"*. I have pasted the code snippet below.

```
String responseP1 = userInput.next();
String[] response1 = responseP1.split(" ");
 for (int I = 0; I<response1.lenght; I++){
    if (response[I].equalsIgnoreCase("hi") 
      && response[I].equalsIgnoreCase("how") 
      && response[I].equalsIgnoreCase("you")){
         System.out.println("It works")
 }
}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Please change `I` to `i` in the loop, it's weird :/

Comment: `response[I].equalsIgnoreCase("hi") &&    response[I].equalsIgnoreCase("how") && response[I].equalsIgnoreCase("you")` can be written more concisely as `false`.

Comment: a==b && a==c; When b != c Then the whole expression evaluates to false, and the body of the if never evaluates. To learn more please study [Two element boolean algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-element_Boolean_algebra)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can keep track of the number of words that you want to appear.

```
int words = 0;
for (int I = 0; I<response1.length; I++) {
    if (response[I].equalsIgnoreCase("hi") || response[I].equalsIgnoreCase("how") || response[I].equalsIgnoreCase("you"))
        words++;
}

if (words == 3)
    System.out.println("It works");
```

But the better suggestion is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < keywords.length; ++i)
    if (!responseP1.contains(keywords[i])) 
        System.out.println("It does not work");
```

`keywords` is a list or array consisting of "hi", "how" and "you".

Comment: Thankyou this really helps. All thats left is onwards.

Comment: @AndreSchoultz mark the answer for the sake of the others, if it is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If I see that right, you compare the same string twice, each time with a different one. In other words, response[I] can't equal "hi" AND "how". Change the && to || ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the and operator in the if statements (&&) when you should be using or (||)

Corey